# TypeScript: error when calling a function from a map with generic arguments

Tags: typescript

I have a TypeScript map, `fnMap`, that contains functions with different argument types. I want to create a generic `callFn` function that receives the function key and arguments, and then calls the appropriate function from the map.

I tried the following code, but I get the error: `A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter. (2556)`

```js
function fnStr(str: string) {}
function fnNum(num: number) {}

const fnMap = {
  fnStr, fnNum
}

type FnMap = typeof fnMap;
type FnKey = keyof FnMap
type Fn<K extends FnKey> = FnMap[K]
type FnArgs<K extends FnKey> = Parameters<Fn<K>>

function callFn<K extends FnKey>(key: K, args: FnArgs<K>) {
  fnMap[key](...args) // <- error here
}
```

[Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMMBlKAnAFAZ0wLkTwxjAHMBKRAbwF8AoUSWBZMAORAFssxvC+XAEYBTDFTr16EBHjYBZAIYAHRAF4a9RG3QYANG05d6DelACeykYgBiYJao0WrcYApUBuM5et2A0iLm6ogA1oGutvYq3laRADx+iCIAHlAiYAAmOJEB5gB8wXYOANp+ALoxvmAAghhkOAlJqelZOYEFGgAKihiKXCJpGA12CXl5UkzQ8EgQigA2cyOJKWmZ2f7tWGHmhH4GPfWEdrX1oxJa7srF22VYAHQPBzgUJkA)

Comment: TS doesn't understand generic conditional types; it's best to refactor as described in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) to a version where your types are written as generic indexed accesses instead; see [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/we6vaN).  Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks, the solution that you provided works for me too.